# Erorr : "Invalid device ordinal value (2). Valid range is [0, 1]. while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 2"

Tags: linux, graphics-card, python, gpu

I am trying to train a neural network for a purpose of Object detection on a server has gpu. 
 I have an environment under the name of ashrf_py.
Jupyter Notebook is used, python3, keras and TensorFlow backend.
when I go for training, I get an error even though I do not choose the device number.

```
Epoch 1/40
Exception: Invalid device ordinal value (2). Valid range is [0, 1].
    while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 2
```

you may tell me to use this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

I have used it. And here what I've got:

```
2019-04-15 11:20:45.292918: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-04-15 11:20:45.314574: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3696000000 Hz
2019-04-15 11:20:45.316533: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x55ded4474170 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-04-15 11:20:45.316600: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-04-15 11:20:45.381103: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-04-15 11:20:45.385630: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:194] StreamExecutor cuda device (2) is of insufficient compute capability: 3.5 required, device is 3.0
2019-04-15 11:20:45.478423: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-04-15 11:20:45.483172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-04-15 11:20:45.483940: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x55ded3ee4d60 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-04-15 11:20:45.483955: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1080, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-04-15 11:20:45.483963: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (1): GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, Compute Capability 6.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/media/DeepData/gpu-users/ashraf/.conda/envs/ashraf_py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1551, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/media/DeepData/gpu-users/ashraf/.conda/envs/ashraf_py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 676, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid device ordinal value (2). Valid range is [0, 1].
    while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 2
```

The graphic cards specifications are shown in the block below. The output comes from "nvidia-smi"

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.48                 Driver Version: 410.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8    10W / 120W |    161MiB /  6078MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 650...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 30%   34C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     33MiB /  1999MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8    17W / 210W |    123MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1935      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            24MiB |
|    0     18504      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            61MiB |
|    0     31427      C   ...ashraf/.conda/envs/ashraf_py/bin/python    63MiB |
|    1                    Not Supported                                       |
|    2     31427      C   ...ashraf/.conda/envs/ashraf_py/bin/python   111MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I appreciate any help in this issue, even simple explenation will help.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved!

The computer was unable to run the basic gpu tensorflow program "The matrecies multiplication".

The point here is the computer that I was working on has 3 GPUs. Later I discovered that one of these cards weren't working. Even when determining which GPU to work got no difference.

After removing/disconnecting the non-working GPU-card the program works perfectly with null errors.